# C++ Callbacks using Boost Functions and C++ Class Methods

Tags: c++, class, boost, function, methods

Is there a non-hacky (i.e. no assembly, ...) way to use boost functions to create callbacks with non-static class methods?

Currently for static methods:

```
list<function<void (LuaState&)> > _callbacks;
```

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
list<tuple<function<void (void *, LuaState&)>, void*> _callbacks;
```

but boost functions doesn't like those `void*`s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function<void (LuaState&)> on_whatever
    = bind(&my_class::my_method, &my_object_of_type_my_class, _1);
```

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of that. Let me try it out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the following?

bind(&my_class::my_method, &my_object_of_type_my_class, _1);

Comment: that depends on the arguments you need to pass to the method and where do you want to take then from. Read boost::bind documentation.

Comment: Obviously, he needs to pass a reference to an object of type `LuaState`. ;-)